# Turning an Integer Value into a Date Using that Integer and the Current Month

Tags: javascript, date

I have a function in my MongoDB/Node backend where I calculate a `nextPaymentDate` based on a combination of the current date and value(s) in a field (which is an array) titled `paymentDateInts`.

I have some logic that determines what is the correct integer of these two  to assign to `nextPaymentDateInt`. This looks like this:

```
  let currentDate = new Date();
  let currentDateInt = currentDate.getDate();
  let paymentDateInts = [1, 15];
  let firstDateInt = paymentDateInts[0];
  let secondDateInt = paymentDateInts[1];

  let nextPaymentDateInt;

  if (firstDateInt < currentDateInt) {
    nextPaymentDateInt = firstDateInt;
  } else {
    nextPaymentDateInt = secondDateInt;
  }
```

However, I want `nextPaymentDate` to be a date, not an integer. So how do I take the integer returned from the above function, and then turn that into a date.

**UPDATE:**

It just occurred to me that this is a little more complicated than I first assumed. Because I need to generate a date using that integer and *either* the current month, *or* the following month - whichever should apply.

In other words, if the second value is 15, and today is the 10th, then I should get a date with the current month and the integer 15. However, if today's date is beyond that 15th, then the date calculated should be for the next month and the integer 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[the `new Date(year, monthIndex, day);` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Syntax)** to construct your `Date` object

```
let nextPaymentDate = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), nextPaymentDateInt);
```

**Note:**

There's no need to declare useless variables such as  `paymentDateInts`, `firstDateInt`  and `secondDateInt`, just compare the `currentDateInt` with `15` and construct your `Date` accordingly:

```
let currentDate = new Date();
let currentDateInt = currentDate.getDate();

let nextPaymentDate;

if (15 >= currentDateInt) {
  nextPaymentDate = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth(), currentDateInt);
} else {
  nextPaymentDate = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth() + 1, 1);
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
let currentDate = new Date();
let currentDateInt = currentDate.getDate();

var nextPaymentDate;

if (15 >= currentDateInt) {
  nextPaymentDate = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth(), currentDateInt);
} else {
  nextPaymentDate = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth() + 1, 1);
}
console.log(nextPaymentDate);
```

Comment: Thanks. To clarify, those "needless variables" are there because here I am using those as placeholders while testing. I will be pulling in values dynamically and assigning them to these variables in the real-world situation. So they won't always be 1 and 15.

Comment: @Muirik I meant you can just compare with the second value which is `15` in our case, and build the `Date` accordingly.

Comment: Right. Okay, gotcha. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As chŝdk says, you can write this in a lot less code, and you only need one Date. Just check the date with `paymentDateInts[1]`, then set values accordingly:

```js
var paymentDateInts = [1, 15];
var d = new Date();

if (d.getDate() < paymentDateInts[1]) {
  d.setDate(paymentDateInts[1]);

} else {
  d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 1, paymentDateInts[0]);
}

console.log(d.toString());
```

Comment: Elegant solution. I like it!

Answer (score 0):

If you want toget a date at the same month then use getFullYear(), getMonth() when creating a new Date:

```
let nextPaymentDate = new Data(currentDate.getFullYear(), currentDate.getMonth(), nextPaymentDateInt)
```

Else, if you need next month, then use `currentDate.getMonth() + 1`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the setDate method. For example

```
let firstDateInteger = new Date();
firstDateInteger.setDate(paymentDateInts[0]);
```